# Cannot run yii application after installing it

Tags: php, yii

I have installed Yii framework from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii and I have followed the required steps mentioned in the same page.

I face the following error, even though I uncomment date settings in `php.ini`. Any idea tqs.

```
Error 500
```

`date()`: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the `date_default_timezone_set()` function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

Regards,
Jimmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your php.ini and set the timezone you want.

Or do it on a per-script basis.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Run this in any script to see what its currently set to ( if it is )

```
phpinfo();
```

Comment: I found the problem. Actually my apache cannot identify which php application to be used because my php.ini is not set properly.

Nevertheless, your answer consist of phpinfo() give me the clue to verify that to work.